# AutoLayout fails, black background and autoresizing masks show up in any case

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, autosize

I made a `UIView` in a StoryBoard containing six `UIButtons`.
I wrote some constraints to support landscape mode as well as portrait mode and put them in two different Arrays: `portraitModeConstraints` and `landscapeModeConstraints`.
When the mode changes, the old constraints are removed and the right array gets added.

When i load the view in portrait mode there is no problem. All Constraints work fine, but wen i turn the iOS-Simulator, i'm getting a lot of warnings. But my constraints work, i tested them. The constraints that make problems are the ones from the autoResizingMask. So i turned them of on my view controller using

> [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

This made no change. So i debugged a little bit and found out that there is no difference between `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO` and `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES`
That is really strange and i can't understand this behaviour.
However, i deleted the constraints manually like this:

> [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];

Now, the constraints worked perfectly in both portrait and landscape (the UIButtons were at the right positions) but the background of my `UIView` turned black and the background image was gone.

EDIT: When the device will rotate, a function on my `viewController` is called:

> willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;

In there i check wether the `toInterfaceOrientation` is landscape or portrait.
When it is portrait, i do this:

> [self.view removeConstraints:self.landscapeModeConstraints];
>   [self.view addConstraints:[NSArray arrayWithArray:self.portraitModeConstraints]];
>   [self.view layoutSubviews];

And when it is landscape i do this

> [self.view removeConstraints:self.portraitModeConstraints];
>   [self.view addConstraints:[NSArray arrayWithArray:self.landscapeModeConstraints]];
>   [self.view layoutSubviews];

Comment: Show the code you're now using to change the constraints on rotation. What do you mean by "now the constraints work perfectly" -- if they did, your view wouldn't be black, and your background image wouldn't be gone.

Comment: It's hard to tell anything from your posted code. How is the background image of your view added? What constraints does it have? I suspect that you're either not adding them back or at least not all of them -- its size is probably zero. BTW, since portraitModeConstraints is an array, there's no need to use [NSArray arrayWithArray... ,  just write, [self.view addConstraints:self.portraitModeConstraints];

Comment: I found a really small mistake in one of my constraints. It works perfectly now. Thanks for the help

Comment: what was the small error in your constraints? (having similar issue)

Answer (score 1):

Stack with the same problem, when controller is embedded in nav controller, and i'm doing `self.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` the view is black. Actually there is no reason to set transl..... on self.view. You need to apply it to subviews. [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AdoptingAutoLayout/AdoptingAutoLayout.html)